# I can't underestand how move semantics work to std::string

Tags: c++

```cpp
explicit Foo(std::string p_str) : m_str(std::move(p_str)) { ... }
```

[Full source code](https://ideone.com/JJwcBQ)

I've made a constructor takes argument with move semantics. (`p_str` -> `m_str`) For a closer look, I opened the library header file `basic_string.h` but there is one thing that I can't understand.

```cpp
basic_string(basic_string&& __str) noexcept :
         _M_dataplus(_M_local_data(), std::move(__str._M_get_allocator())) {
     if (__str._M_is_local()) {
         traits_type::copy(_M_local_buf, __str._M_local_buf, _S_local_capacity + 1);
     } else {
         _M_data(__str._M_data());
         _M_capacity(__str._M_allocated_capacity);
     }

     _M_length(__str.length());
     __str._M_data(__str._M_local_data());  // (#)
     __str._M_set_length(0);
 }
```

This is move constructor of `basic_string` class. After `(#)` is executed, `p_str` turns to `".\000\000\000\000\000\000\000..."`. As I know, `basic_string` stores strings in the array `_M_local_buf` and method `_M_local_data()` returns its address.

Then, why `__str._M_data(__str._M_local_data());` changes `p_str` to zero-filled string? Isn't `p_str`(`__str`) still having the original strings?

Comment: `__str` and `p_str` are the same string. So obviously `__str._M_data(__str._M_local_data());` changes `p_str`. BTW this code looks like it's implementing small string optimization (SSO). `_M_data` is the address of the character data, `_M_local_data()` is the address of a small string only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is short string optimization.

libstdc++'s `std::string` implementation has two places it can store string data.  It stores long strings in a dynamically allocated array of `char`s.  To avoid the overhead of allocating that array, it can also store short strings in the space it usually uses to track the size of that dynamically allocated array.  That's `_M_local_data`.

`_M_dataplus._M_p` holds a pointer to the first element of whicherver buffer is currently in use.  That's the pointer that `_M_data()` returns, and the pointer that `_M_data(pointer)` sets.

So putting that together, doing

```
__str._M_data(__str._M_local_data());
__str._M_set_length(0);
```

is telling the moved-from string "Forget about any buffer you were previously managing, start using your local buffer for storage, and assume you hold no data".

---

> Then, why `__str._M_data(__str._M_local_data());` changes `p_str` to zero-filled string?

It doesn't.  It changes `p_str`'s data pointer to point to the memory that previously held the size of its externally-allocated array.  What you're seeing are the leftovers of that capacity (Did `p_str` have a capacity of `46` by chance?  That's the ASCII code point for `'.'`).  For the moment between those two lines, `p_str` is in an inconsistent state.  Its size is still set to its previous size, but the buffer it now points to doesn't hold that number of characters.  That gets rectified on the next line when the move constructor sets its length to `0`.

Comment: By the way, setting the source string empty is unnecessary work if SSO is used since the standard doesn't guarantee that the moved-from string is empty. I would certainly ask what the point is in a code review.

Comment: @ArneVogel If they didn't set it to empty they would have to put _something_ in that memory.  At that point if the moved-from string _wasn't_ using its `_M_local_data` member then it would be an inactive union member, and reading from it would be undefined.  It may also not be long enough to hold `size()` characters.  The standard guarantees that the moved-from object will be in an unspecified _valid_ state.  Reading from `str[str.size() - 1]` has to be a well-defined operation if `size()` > 0.

Comment: No, they don't. I'm referring to the case where the source string is already using SSO, they can then simply leave the original object alone and only copy over the contents. To claim that this leaves the source in an invalid state is to claim that it was already in an invalid state upon entering the constructor, because it wasn't changed. (If it's not using SSO, then, yes, they have to change it to prevent aliasing / double free etc.)

Comment: @ArneVogel Ah, yes, in that case you're right.  I suspect they did it that way just to make the code a bit cleaner and/or to protect people who assume the moved-from string will be empty, but I don't know for sure why the libstdc++ developers made that that choice.

Answer (score 1):

Your `std::string` stores its contents in one of two ways:

- If the string is short, it is stored directly in `_M_local_buf`, which is presumably an array member of `std::string` (and also accessible via `_M_local_data()`).
- If the string is long, a `char` array is allocated separately and a pointer to it is stored in `_M_p` (which is also accessible via `_M_data()`).

The `if` statement deals with the two possible representations:

- If the contents are stored directly in the `std::string` object (`__str._M_is_local()`), we copy the data into our own `_M_local_buf` array.
- Otherwise we simply copy the pointer (as returned by `_M_data()`) and capacity.

  Right now our objects are in an inconsistent state: Both `this->_M_data()` and `__str._M_data()` point to the same allocated storage; they both "own" it. To resolve this situation, we need to reset `__str` so it won't try to free our string data out from under us when it is destroyed. We'll do that in a second.

`_M_length(__str.length());` copies over the length value from `__str`.

`__str._M_data(__str._M_local_data());` makes `_M_p` point to the internal array that is part of the `__str` object. If `__str` wasn't a short string to begin with, this array contains garbage. But that doesn't matter, because:

`__str._M_set_length(0)` resets the length of `__str` to 0. The contents of `__str._M_local_buf` don't matter because 0 of them are "valid", i.e. part of the string.

In short: This move constructor copies the member variables of `__str` into our new object, then makes `__str` an empty string. (The string contents have been "moved" from `__str` into `*this`, so now `__str` is empty.)

This is a general principle: Moving from a variable destroys its contents. It will be a valid object (a valid `std::string` in this case), but you cannot rely on any data still being there.